# How to code split one of two entries in Webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, code-splitting, webpack-4

I’ve got a seemingly pretty straightforward Webpack code splitting setup that I’m having trouble migrating to Webpack 4. I have two entries, called `main` and `preview`. I want to do an initial code split into a `vendor` chunk for the vendor modules in `main`, but I want to keep `preview` as a single chunk.

Relevant part of the working configuration in Webpack 3:

```
{
  entry: {
    main: './src/application.js',
    preview: './src/preview.js',
  },
  plugins: [{
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      chunks: ['main'],
      minChunks({context}) {
        if (!context) {
          return false;
        }
        const isNodeModule = context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
        return isNodeModule;
      },
    }),
  }]
}
```

Specifically, using the `chunks` property in the `CommonsChunkPlugin` options allows me to do what I need to do easily. Is there an equivalent in Webpack 4’s `optimization.splitChunks` configuration?

Answer (score 7):

The following Webpack 4 config only splits `main` module vendor dependencies into a separate chunk. Other dependencies for `preview` remains within that chunk.

```
{
    entry: {
        main: './test/application.js',
        preview: './test/preview.js'
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                    priority: 1,
                    test(module, chunks) {
                        const name = module.nameForCondition && module.nameForCondition();
                        return chunks.some(chunk => chunk.name === 'main' && /node_modules/.test(name));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Shared dependencies are  included in the vendors bundle unless we configure the `preview` cacheGroup with higher priority to enforce that all dependencies included here should remain inside this chunk.

For more Webpack 4 related info/config you can review this [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project.

---

In order to enforce splitting all vendors dependencies from `main` and reuse them from `main` and `preview` chunks you must configure the `preview` cacheGroup as:

```
preview: {
    name: 'preview',
    chunks: 'all',
    enforce: true,
    priority: 0,
    test(module, chunks) {
        return chunks.some(chunk => chunk.name === 'preview');
    }
}
```

Note that the cacheGroup for `preview` chunk has lower priority than the `vendors` one to ensures that all `main` dependencies which are also dependencies in `preview` are also referenced from the `preview` bundle.

Comment: Thank you! My goal is for the `preview` bundle to totally self-contained, so it sounds like I will need to configure a higher-priority `cacheGroup` for it. However, I’d still like for dependencies used in both `preview` and `main` to be split into the `vendor` chunk for `main`’s purposes. Is that possible?

Comment: Your'e welcome. In order to move all dependencies from `main` (including the shared ones with `preview`) you need to add the cacheGroup config for `preview` with lower priority to avoids this chunk to be splitted but also re-use shared dependencies (references dependencies already extracted from `main` to `vendors`). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Or:

```js
splitChunks: {
  cacheGroups: {
    vendors: {
      test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
      name: "vendors",
      // Exclude preview dependencies going into vendors.
      chunks: chunk => chunk.name !== "preview"
    },
  },
},
```

Please read the [documentation of `chunks`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkschunks) for more details.

Comment: For future readers: Notice that each entry itself is a chunk. And this answer is what I'm using, since more elegant.