# How split code with webpack 4 with different module

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm moving my project to Webpack 4, from an old grunt + requirejs configuration.
This is my file structure:

```
- node_modules
- main.js
- app.js
- file1.js
- file2.js
- file3.js
- apps
   - login
     - login_app.js
     - login_view.js
     - login_controller.js
   - home
     - home_app.js
     - home_view.js
     - home_controller.js
   ...

main.js:

import APP from 'app.js';
import file3 from 'file3.js';

app.js:

import file1 from 'file1.js'
import file2 from 'file2.js'
import file3 from 'file3.js'

..
import some node_modules library
..


login_app.js:

import login_view.js
import login_controller.js
..
import some node_modules library
..

home_app.js:

import home_view.js
import home_controller.js
..
import some node_modules library
..
```

So my idea with the code splitting webpack feature is to achieve this builds:

main.js (contain app.js + file1..3)
vendor.js (contain node_modules lib)

login.js (contain login_view + login_controller + (node_modules lib used only here? it this righit)

home.js (contain home_view + home_controller + (node_modules lib used only here? it this right)

I have searched a lot on the web, and I found this answer:

[How to code split one of two entries in Webpack 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298706/how-to-code-split-one-of-two-entries-in-webpack-4)

So using something like this:

```
cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                    priority: 1,
                    test(module, chunks) {
                        const name = module.nameForCondition && module.nameForCondition();
                        return chunks.some(chunk => chunk.name === 'main' && /node_modules/.test(name));
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have tried in my code but I can't achieve a right solution. can someone tell me what is the right way?