# Webpack - How to create independent entry point (ignore cacheGroups settings)?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, bundling-and-minification, webpack-5

In my webpack config I created 2 cache groups, "vendors" and "common".

```
        entry: {
            'entry1': './src/entry1.js',
            'entry2_independent': './src/entry2_independent.js',
        },
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendors: {
                        minChunks: 30,
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        name: 'vendors',
                        priority: -10,
                        chunks: 'initial'
                    },
                    default: {
                        minChunks: 30,
                        priority: -20,
                        chunks: 'initial',
                        reuseExistingChunk: true,
                        name: 'common'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

I want one of my entry points to be independent. It should include all its dependencies without being depndent on common.js or vendors.js.

To be more specific, I want all entry points with '_independent' in their name, to be independent.

I still want to preserve the optimization logic. 
If a module is used in 30 chunks, I still want it to be part of the 'common' layer.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to code split one of two entries in Webpack 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298706/how-to-code-split-one-of-two-entries-in-webpack-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up exporting 2 configs. One which has common layer (common/vendors) and another which creates independent/standalone bundles:

```
module.exports = function (env) {

    const baseConfig = {
        mode: env.development ? 'development' : 'production',
        devtool: 'source-map',
        watch: !!env.development,
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, CONSTS.DIST),
            filename: '[name].js',
            chunkFilename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: '/dist/scripts/',
            globalObject: 'this',
        }
    };

    const clientConfig = Object.assign({}, baseConfig, {
        entry: {
            'client-entry1': './src/entry1.js',
            'client-entry2': './src/entry2.js',
        },
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendors: {
                        minChunks: 30,
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        name: 'vendors',
                        priority: -10,
                        chunks: 'initial'
                    },
                    default: {
                        minChunks: 30,
                        priority: -20,
                        chunks: 'initial',
                        reuseExistingChunk: true,
                        name: 'common'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    const serverConfig = Object.assign({}, baseConfig, {
        entry: {
            'independent-bundle1': './src/entry1_independent.js',
            'independent-bundle2': './src/entry2_independent.js',
        }
    });

    return [clientConfig, serverConfig];
};
```

If somebody have a better solution which doesn't require 2 different configs, please share :)

Answer (score 1):

Return true in name function for all the files that you want to be in that specific cache group

Function name will run on all files that their path match `all_files_that_match_this_regex_will_run_name_func`.

If the function will return true, this file will be embedded in `common` chunk.

```
 common: {
   test: /<all_files_that_match_this_regex_will_run_name_func>/,
   name(fileName) {
      const filePath = fileName.context;
      const regexForFilesInCommonChunks = /isShouldBeInCommon/

      if (regexForFilesInCommonChunks.test(filePath)) {
          return 'common'
      }

      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Raz, thanks for the answer.
It's not working for me. Even when I'm implementing the above logic, the common modules are included only in common.js, and  not in both common.js and entry2_independent.js.

Again, to clarify:
in case a bundle contains '_independent' in the file name, common modules should be included in both files XXXX_independent and common.js.

Answer (score 0):

> I want one of my entry points to be independent. [...]

Notice that all entry points are mutual-independent by default. The most common mistake a naive user might make is module-duplication among entries. Instead, you can use [`dependOn`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#dependencies) for one entry to reuse all modules from another one. I think this is another approach than yours, which is also a good practice in my opinion: no-use means not-related.